# Why does caffe io load_image normalize rgb values of png files from 0-1?

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

The `caffe.io.load_image()` function call on a png, returns a numpy 3d array, with the rgb values as normalized floats in the 0-1 range instead of 0-255.

Is this:

1. common practice when loading images into array like structures?
2. have something to do with how the caffe network layers uses the images?
3. something to do with how png files are stored?

Thanks

Comment: in what way [`caffe.io.load_imgae()`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/io.py#L285-L309) normalizes the image? Can you be more specific?

Comment: the values are in 0-1 range instead of 0-255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizing pixel values to range `[0..1]` (instead of `[0..255]`) is common practice not only in deep learning, but also in other domains of image-processing/computer-vision.
This is mainly done since the native `uint8` pixel values are not easy to work with - `uint8` easily over/underfloat. Therefore, it is more convenient to convert pixel values to `float` type in range `[0..1]`.

Trying to cope with vanishing/exploding gradients in deep nets, there are many theoretical papers analyzing the distribution of activation values (see e.g., [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852)). These works usually assume a normal distribution of values - thus the scaling. You will also come across many nets that in addition to scaling the nets subtract "image mean" from the input.